# How to use PHP Laravel Eloquent groupBy and sum method with two related models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have three models `Country`, `Province` and `District`. `Country` has a one-to-many relationship with both `Province` and `District` models. And `Province` has a one-to-many relationship with `District` model. The `District` model has `province_id` as a foreign key.

In the `District` model I have a population to sum. I want to get the sum of a population for each province.

```
$population = Country::where(['name' => $c_name])->first()->districts;
$num = $population->groupBy('province_id')->map(function ($row) {
    return $row->sum('population_m');
});
```

SQL Query:

```
SELECT provinces.name, SUM(districts.population_m) AS population_m, SUM(districts.population_f) AS population_f FROM provinces
LEFT JOIN districts ON provinces.id = districts.province_id
GROUP BY provinces.name;
```

The above returns the province id but I want the province name with it.

Comment: The way you wrote our your problem, it appears you're asking two questions,  1 . **I want to get the sum of a population for each province.** 2. **The above returns the province id but I want the province name with it.** which are you asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are telling it to group by province_id: `$population->groupBy('province_id')`. Instead, you can pass a function to the `groupBy()` collection method to tell it how to group the items inside:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby

Try something like this:

```
$population = Country::where(['name' => $c_name])->first()->districts;
$num = $population->groupBy(function($district, $key) {
    return $district->province->name;
})->map(function ($row) {
    return $row->sum('population_m');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$population = Country::where(['name' => $c_name])->first()->districts()->with('province')->get();
```